# Number of solutions of $x^{2}+y^{2}=625$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$B=\left\{\left(x,y\right)\mid x^{2}+y^{2}=625 \quad x,y\in \mathbb N\right\}$
What is the number of elements of $B$?

Comment: Your formatting was right, but to use math mode use $ to open and close the math mode.

Comment: What does mean $n(B)$?

Comment: Probably number of elements of $B$ .

Comment: Yes, it must be. Thank you @Aboozar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^2 + y^2 = 625 \implies x^2 = 625 -y^2 \implies x^2 = (25-y)(25+y)$
Hence $(25-y)(25+y)$ should be square number and then by checking $y=1,2,...,25$ we can deduce :
$y = 7 , 15 , 20 , 24 $
Because other possibilities are remove quickly.
For example if $y=11$ then $25 - y = 14$ and $25+ y = 36 $ and $14$ isn't square.